# Checkbox sin formulario en Struts1

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts

Estoy manteniendo y mejorando en mi trabajo una aplicación heredada (y muy obsoleta) basada en `Struts 1.x` y `Java 1.4.2.` La aplicación en sí tiene una estructura tal que cada una de sus funcionalidades muestra de inicio una lista, y en ningún caso se usaba checkboxes en esas listas. Ahora estoy implementando una lista diferente que sí usa checkboxes y debo recoger los valores de los checkboxes seleccionados y operar con ellos en el backend. El problema es que, como he dicho, los checkboxes se encuentran en una lista y no en un formulario, y la funcionalidad pedida es que mediante menú emergente se genere (click derecho, generar) un informe partiendo de la información seleccionada. Un checkbox cualquiera podría ser como el siguiente:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1608017825">
```

El problema reside tanto en mantener los checkboxes con la paginación como en recoger una lista de los mismos que estén seleccionados. Necesitaría una pequeña ayuda o sugerencia o idea (no pido código) para saber por donde tirar, dado que aunque llevo manteniendo esta aplicación más de año y medio, todo lo implementado ha sido por imitación e ingeniería inversa, sin disponer en ningún caso de documentación alguna. Por tanto mi manejo con Struts 1.x es algo limitado.

Comment: Entiendo que los checkboxes no están asociados a ninguna clase o variable, ¿No? De ser así yo personalmente optaría por recoger los valores mediante javascript y enviarlos al backend mediante una petición ajax.

Comment: Entiendo que desde *click derecho - generar* vas a invocar una función javascript que llamará a algo que genera el informe. Pues en la función js recorre el documento, recoge todos los elementos de tipo *checkbox*, recupera el valor etc. Algo así. O si prefieres cada vez que haces click en el checkbox lo guardas en una variable javascript de la página. El problema de todo esto es cómo hacer las cosas con la paginación. Como no sé cómo la tienes implementada... ¿Al paginar recargas la página o solo parte del contenido?

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Los checkboxes de momento no están asociados a nada. Dado que esta es una aplicación muy acotada en cuanto a usuarios y está dentro de una red privada, me estaba planteando lo que dices de recoger los valores con javascript (o jquery), pero meter la lista de valores en el request mediante un scriptlet y luego lanzar la llamada ajax.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev la paginación recarga la página completa.

Comment: Entonces ajax, no te queda otra - recoges los valores seleccionados y lanzas una petición ajax. Ya en el servidor sabrás lo que tienes que hacer con los datos ;-)

Comment: Al final lo resolví usando jQuery y el almacenamiento de sesión :)